# Chaining results with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, bluebird

Is there any convenience method in [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for a resolution chain where the input for each element is the resolved value from the previous element (unless it is not a function)?

I'm trying to chain the following logic into a single method:

```
function getClient() {
    // resolves with the client
}

function getClientProduct(client) {
    // resolves with the product
}

var response = {}; // global response object;

function prepareResponse(product) {
    // prepares global response object, resolves with `undefined`
}

promise.someMethod(getClient, getClientProduct, prepareResponse, response)
    .then(data=> {
        // data = the response object;
    });
```

I'd like to avoid having to write the following (if possible):

```
getClient()
    .then(client=>getClientProduct(client))
    .then(product=>prepareResponse(product))
    .then(()=>response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those arrow functions are meaningless. You can do simply

```
getClient().then(getClientProduct).then(prepareResponse).…
```

There is no convenience method to shorten that further - I guess you don't want to consider

```
[getClient, getClientProduct, prepareResponse].reduce((p,fn)=>p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())
```

For the last one, you can use the [`.return(response)` utility method](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/return.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you! I thought I missed something, because this would be a nice feature ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a convenience method. You can just write it like this:

```
function getClient() {
    // resolves with the client
}

function getClientProduct(client) {
    // resolves with the product
}

var response = {}; // global response object;

function prepareResponse(product) {
    // prepares global response object, resolves with `undefined`
}

getClient()
    .then(getClientProduct)
    .then(prepareResponse)
    .return(response);
```